# how to execute one script from another

Tags: python

I am new in working with python and working on API of XenServer

I am trying to start a script which uses the XenServer API to start a virtual machine upon receiving the data from the client. The code is below

```
import socket
import json
import startvm

ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
print("ip of server machiene  = " + ip  )

# create a socket object
serversocket = socket.socket(
socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 9999

# bind to the port
serversocket.bind((host, port))

print ("server is waiting for data")

# queue up to 5 requests
serversocket.listen(5)

 running = True

 while True:

# establish a connection
clientsocket, addr = serversocket.accept()

print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr))

while running:
    receivedData = clientsocket.recv(1024)
    #json = receivedData

    if receivedData:

        print (receivedData)
        execfile(startvm.py)

    else:

        print (" -- data end --" )
        running = False

serversocket.close()
```

I am using execute(script name). and it gives me the following error

on the server side script

```
ip of server machine  = 192.168.0.11
server is waiting for data
Traceback (most recent call last):
Got a connection from ('127.0.0.1', 50128)
  File "/Users/jasmeet/IdeaProjects/vKey-cloud/server.py", line 45, in 
<module>
0
  execfile(startvm.py)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'py'
```

and this on client script

```
connecting to server at 127.0.0.1 on port 9999
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jasmeet/IdeaProjects/vKey-cloud/client.py", line 27, in 
  <module>
clientSocket.send(str(x))
socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

can anybody explain me how to do it exactly thank you in advance

Comment: execfile takes filename/filepath as string `try execfile('startvm.py')`

Answer (score 0):

you could import the file at the beginning like:

```
from startvm.py import A_FUNCTION_FROM_THAT_FILE
```

so that it's optimized
and replace

```
execfile(startvm.py)
```

with

```
A_FUNCTION_FROM_THAT_FILE(*args)
```

ex:

```
# script A.py
from B.py import customfunc
customfunc(2, 4)

# script B.py
def customfunc(x, y):
    return x*y
```

Answer (score 0):

writing the following code for `server.py` solved my problem

```
    # server.py
import socket
import json
import startvm

ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
print("ip of server machiene  = " + ip  )

# create a socket object
serversocket = socket.socket(
    socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# get local machine name
#host = socket.gethostname()
#port = 9999 # port 80

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 9999

# bind to the port
serversocket.bind((host, port))

print ("server is waiting for data")

# queue up to 5 requests
serversocket.listen(5)



while True:
    running = True
    # establish a connection
    clientsocket, addr = serversocket.accept()

    print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr))

    while running:
        receivedData = clientsocket.recv(1024)
        #json = receivedData

        if receivedData:

            print (receivedData)
            #execfile('startvm.py')

        else:

            print (" -- data end --" )
            running = False
```